# Azure cli: clone pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Looking at [az pipelines documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest) it seems it's not possible to clone a pipeline using cli.

I've looked at getting the yaml (`az pipelines show -name=x > x_orig.yaml`) and then trying to change json and create pipeline from modified yaml, but that feels like a lot of work that could break after next update.

Is there a way to clone a pipline without going the the Web UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there indeed is not available Azure CLI that can clone or export/import a pipeline to create a new pipeline.

I also searched and tried the [Azure DevOps REST API for Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), but did not find the available API.

Ideally, the Azure CLI "[**az pipelines create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_pipelines_create)" can provide an input parameter that allows users specify an existing pipeline as a starting point for the new pipeline.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend that you can directly report a feature request on the "[**Azure/azure-cli**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/new?template=Feature_request.md)" repository to ask adding the parameter like as above mentioned. That will allow you directly interact with the appropriate engineering team, and make it more convenient for the engineering team to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we could clone the build definition via power shell script to call REST API.

**Note**: We need to change the original build definition name.

REST API

Get build definition:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=6.0
```

Create build definition

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0
```

Power shell script

```
$connectionToken="{pat}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$BuildDefinitionInfoURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/definitions/386" 
$BuildDefinitionInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $BuildDefinitionInfoURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get 
Write-Host $BuildDefinitionInfo.name

$BuildDefinitionInfo.name = $BuildDefinitionInfo.name +" clone"

Write-Host $BuildDefinitionInfo.name

$body = $BuildDefinitionInfo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
$createBuildDefinitionURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $createBuildDefinitionURL -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST

Write-Host $response.id
```

Result:

[image]